# How do I tokenize a string from a list of known tokens?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have a list of tokens, used to generate faux-Japanese words, that looks like this:

```
var syllables = ["chi","tsu","shi","ka","ki","ku","ke","ko","ta","te","to","sa","su","se","so","na","ni","nu","ne","no","ha","hi","fu","he","ho","ma","mi","mu","me","mo","ya","yu","yo","ra","ri","ru","re","ro","wa","wo"];
```

Given a word like "yoniyotachihochinitarehakemukenushihofure", is it possible to split it into separate tokens into an array like ["yo","ni","yo"... using RegExps?

So far, I have

```
  var s="";
  for(var i=0;i<syllables.length;i++)
    s+=("("+syllables[i]+")");
  s+="+";
  console.log(s);
  var splitregex = new RegExp(s,"gi");
  console.log(str.split(splitregex));
```

and I get back "[ 'yoniyotachihochinitarehakemukenushihofure' ]"

Comment: Also relevant: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Automated-Curse-Generator.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var syllables = ["chi","tsu","shi","ka","ki","ku","ke","ko","ta","te","to","sa","su","se","so","na","ni","nu","ne","no","ha","hi","fu","he","ho","ma","mi","mu","me","mo","ya","yu","yo","ra","ri","ru","re","ro","wa","wo"];

var r = new RegExp(syllables.join('|'), 'g');

var str = 'yoniyotachihochinitarehakemukenushihofure';

console.log(str.match(r));
// return ["yo", "ni", "yo", "ta", "chi", "ho", "chi", "ni", "ta", "re", "ha", "ke", "mu", "ke", "nu", "shi", "ho", "fu", "re"]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T8LeY/

Explanation: it generates the regex `/chi|tsu|.../g` which simply matches every syllable from the list